# Can't define relative vertical position of div within nested structure

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, vertical-alignment, css-transforms

I'm using [Swipe.js](https://github.com/thebird/swipe/) to create a page with several screens. Swipe requires a structure of 3 nested divs, with some style defined. I want to position an element 70% towards the bottom of one of the screens, but I'm finding that its Y position remains at the top when defined as a percentage. My guess is that the height of the containing div is somehow still 0, though I have set all `min-height` properties to 100%.

I'm testing on Chrome in desktop, for now. My stylesheet:

```
/* required by swipe.js */
.swipe {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%; /* added this everywhere I could just in case */
}

.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.swipe-wrap > div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  min-height: 100%;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* element I want to position */
.myElement {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Body:

```
<div id="slider" class="swipe">
    <div class="swipe-wrap">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="myElement">
                <h1>I should be more than halfway down.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result is that the inner div is centred horizontally, but vertically it's at the top (in fact, cut off because of the `transform` offset).

I have tried using flex and `align-items: center`. That does work. I'm not sure if I can use flex to define arbitrary relative positions, though.

Comment: please right my answers if useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Please check below example

```css
.swipe {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
   height: 100%;
 
}

.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;

}

.swipe-wrap > .page {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
text-align: center;
}
.myElement{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.page {
  min-height: 100%;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="swipe">
    <div class="swipe-wrap">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="myElement">
                <h1>I should be more than halfway down.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like myElement to be at 70% of screen height. Also, you set all heights to 100% but  want to allow for some of my pages to extend beyond the bottom of the screen. That's why I'm using `min-height`.